# после запуска `docker-compose.yml` на ПК появился Linux, как удалить Linux?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

После запуска `docker-compose.yml` (я так думаю) на ПК появился Linux, вот как это выглядит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как полностью удалить `Linux` с моего ПК?

И как он вообще появился на моем ПК?

Может он появился не через `docker-compose.yml`, не знаю (просто я заметил что `Linux` появился после работы с `docker-compose.yml`, к тому же я помню что когда запустил `docker-compose.yml` то почти час ждал на скачивание каких-то образов), но вот если что содержимое файла:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  contoso:
    build: ./
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development

  sqldata:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
    environment:
      - SA_USER=myUsername
      - SA_PASSWORD=myPassword
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - "5434:1433"
```

Comment: Docker в принципе не может работать в Виндовс напрямую (и никогда не мог). Для того, чтобы он мог, (раньше через Hyper-V, а сейчас через WSL) устанавливается виртуальная машина с Линуксом, и Докер гоняется внутри неё. Все инструменты, что ты используешь - `docker`, `docker-compose` и т.д. - это просто интерфейс для взаимодействия с демоном докера (dockerd) внутри виртуальной машины.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, но как мне удалить теперь Linux'a с моего ПК?

Comment: сделать докеру uninstall

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, удалил, но как удалить папку `Linux` (она теперь пустая, но её невозможно удалить)?

Comment: возможно, исчезнет после перезагрузки Виндовс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сайте Майкрософта есть целая статья про это

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/why-there-is-linux-in-my-file-explorer-bar/c7aaca2b-7e7d-4cd2-bb80-6a4cde330433

1. Нужно создать текстовый файл `linux.reg` с содержимым в точности как ниже

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{B2B4A4D1-2754-4140-A2EB-9A76D9D7CDC6}] 
@="Linux" 
"System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{B2B4A4D1-2754-4140-A2EB-9A76D9D7CDC6}]
@="Linux"
```

2. Дабл-клик по созданному файлу, согласиться со всеми вопросами
3. Перезагрузиться

Comment: А как её добавить не устанавливая докер?)

Answer (score 0):

Это директория \wsl.localhost хранит в себе примонтированные образы Linux которые работают в подсистеме WSL Саму директорию можно и не удалять, она никаких ресурсов не занимает, но если хочется то ладно)